# Java Threads - weird behaviour - program jumps between two threads alternatively at certain point

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

[link for the code](https://github.com/shlomi-levi/Maman15Question2/blob/master/mainClass.java)
(It's for homework so don't try to look for logic)

Basically what the program should do is create x (user input) threads and "assign" each thread a value (by using an array of size x).

After that, the program goes through y (user input) rounds where for each round it does the following:

Every thread should check for the assigned values of his "neighbors" have - if his assigned value is smaller than their assigned values then his value will increase by 1, if it's greater than both of these values then his assigned value will decrease by 1, and if it's between them (or equal to one or both of them) his assigned value will remain unchanged

A thread should only change his assigned value after his neighbors have checked him out (in my implementation I'm just doing it at the end of each round)

In addition to that, we are treating the array as a "circular" array, meaning that the right neighbor of the arr[arr.length - 1] is arr[0].

After each round we should print the current status of the array that represents the threads assigned values.

My problem is that after all threads have checked their neighbors assigned values, the program gets stuck jumping between two threads (lines 79-85). I've tried using notifyAll() instead of notify() but it didn't help

Thanks in advance

Comment: “link for the code” When that project changes or disappears, your question will be useless to future readers.  Edit your question and include the code itself in the question.

Comment: FYI: This is a really Bad Idea: `catch(Exception ignored) { }`. There have been numerous questions in this forum where the answer turned out to be that an exception that the OP thought could never happen actually _was_ happening, and their exception handler "swallowed" it without printing or logging anything at all. You should _at least_ put an `ignored.printStackTrace()` in the handler so that you can know if the exception was thrown.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with `notify(); wait();` but that also looks like a Bad Idea. `wait()` and `notify()` are a low-level mechanism that is supposed to be used [in a very specific way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html). Another whole category of questions in this forum comes from people who try to get creative with `wait()` and `notify()`. Maybe a higher-level synchronization object like [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) would be helpful to you.